# Error: Number out of representable range: type FIXED[SB4](1,0){not null}, value 10 on a datetime column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using some recursive CTEs to build a date and time table. This works as expected. However, I cannot do *any* operation to the datetime (timestampntz) column.

This is the simplest form where it returned the error:
**Number out of representable range: type FIXEDSB4{not null}, value 10**

```
with recursive dates as (
    select cast('2023-01-01' as date) as date
    union all
    select date + 1
    from dates
    where dates.date < current_date()
),
hours as (
    select 0 as hour
    union all
    select hour + 1
    from hours
    where hours.hour < 23
),
minutes as (
    select 0 as minute
    union all
    select minute + 1
    from minutes
    where minutes.minute < 59
),
datetimes as (
select timestamp_ntz_from_parts(year(dates.date), month(dates.date), day(dates.date), hours.hour, minutes.minute, 0) dt 
from dates
cross join hours
cross join minutes
)
select *
from datetimes
--up until here it works, but the line below causes the error
where datetimes.dt >= cast('2023-06-01' as timestampntz)
```

I've tried casting the column, still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timestamp does not fit into the allocated integer data type for hours and mins. Try these modified lines in your query:

```
...
hours as (
    select 0::bigint as hour
    union all
    select hour + 1
    from hours
    where hours.hour < 23
),
minutes as (
    select 0::bigint as minute
    union all
    select minute + 1
    from minutes
    where minutes.minute < 59
),
...
```

It will convert data types to bigint.

Comment: You can just cast them as integer, rather than bigint. I think this is a feature (bug!) in Snowflake - because you initially set the column value to 0 it internally assumes the virtual column datatype to be number(1) and then errors out later when the data in this column doesn't actual match this assumed datatype